# Artifactory - Docker Registry _catalog call , returns blank

Tags: artifactory, docker-registry, docker-api, jfrog-container-registry

We have an Artifactory configured as a docker registry and when call is made to `https://artifactory/v2/_catalog`, the catalog call returns blank, rather then listing docker image repositories.

According to https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories this should return repositories.

However, the call to `https://artifactory/v2/docker-repo/_catalog` works.

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you talking to the registry API or the artifactory API? They're going to be on different ports.

Comment: I'm talking to the registry API, I guess if I talked to the Artifactory API the call to https://artifactory/v2/docker-repo/_catalog wouldn't work.

Comment: Is the reverse proxy properly configured? Is `docker-repo` supposed to be in any of the calls? I.e. can you list tags in `docker-repo` or is that a layer too high and the proxy should mask that out.

Comment: We are not using a reverse proxy, we are using the repository-path method, I followed this guide: 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-WithoutaReverseProxy 
                 
Docker-repo is a name of a repo, for example "docker-local", when I do `https://<artifactory-url>/v2/<repo-name>/_catalog`, it works

Comment: In that case, it feels like a bug to report to the vendor. The `_catalog` API is one of those weakly supported API's from Docker that didn't make it into OCI, but from the Docker version was only supposed to be defined at the top level. I say weakly supported because it's not enabled on many SaaS registries like Docker Hub.

Answer (score 0):

For listing the docker repositories from Artifactory, you should refer to this [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ListDockerRepositories) call instead of the normal docker API call.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to configure IBM Vulnerability Advisor (which is a tool that is used to do security checks on images stored in Artifactory) and it uses the v2/_catalog endpoint to retrieve the list of repositories. So I need to find a way to get the docker api working.

Comment: You can think of adding a rewrite rule if you are using any reverse proxy so that any request with v2/_catalog will have the docker-repo request in it.